# How to change result position based off parameter in a mongodb / mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am using mongoose and node.js to access a mongodb database. I want to bump up each result based on a number (they are ordered by date created if none are bumped up). For example:

```
{ name: 'A',
  bump: 0 },

{ name: 'B',
  bump: 0 },

{ name: 'C',
  bump: 2 },

{ name: 'D',
  bump: 1 }
```

would be retreived in the order: C, A, D, B. How can this be accomplished (without iterating through every entry in the database)?

Comment: So you want it to sort according to 1, 2, 1, 0?

Comment: no, I want the result "bumped" up that many results

Comment: Please give an example... "I have x stored in the db. A request comes in. I want it to do y..."

Comment: I thought it was pretty self explanatory, but here: you have a list like: a, b, c, d. 'c' gets +1 on a number field. The list then becomes: a, c, b, d

Comment: No, the question is confusing. Your sorting "rules" don't make sense. What's the use case?

Comment: forum, when somebody upvotes a thread, it gets moved up one result

Comment: I think you need to include more of your schema, a query you tried or a fake one that approximates what you want to do, or something like that.

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to do? lol this is almost exactly what my schema is.

Comment: Are you trying to be mysterious? I think the problem is that the distinction between your query parameters and results is not clear. Are `name` and `bump` what you are sending to the db or are they what already exist in the db or both? If you're posting `bump`, are you sending bumps for different names in one post or do they happen separately? Do you have to find based on name first to know what to bump? Are you storing these names? Describe your set-up and needs in more detail.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the suspicion that you can't accomplish what you're trying to do without looping. But post more info and we'll see...

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. Store a counter tracking the total # of threads, let's call it `thread_count`, initially set to 0, so have a document somewhere that looks like `{thread_count:0}`.

Every time a new thread is created, first call `findAndModify()` using `{$inc : {thread_count:1}}` as the modifier - i.e., increment the counter by 1 and return its new value.

Then when you insert the new thread, use the new value for the counter as the value for a field in its document, let's call it `post_order`.

So each document you insert has a value 1 greater each time. For example, the first 3 documents you insert would look like this:

`{name:'foo', post_order:1, created_at:... }    // value of thread_count is at 1`
`{name:'bar', post_order:2, created_at:... }    // value of thread_count is at 2`
`{name:'baz', post_order:3, created_at:... }    // value of thread_count is at 3`
etc.

So effectively, you can query and order by `post_order` as ASCENDING, and it will return them in the order of oldest to newest (or DESCENDING for newest to oldest).

Then to "bump" a thread in its sorting order when it gets upvoted, you can call `update()` on the document with `{$inc:{post_order:1}}`. This will advance it by 1 in the order of result sorting. If two threads have the same value for post_order, created_at will differentiate which one comes first. So you will sort by `post_order, created_at`.

You will want to have an index on `post_order` and `created_at`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's guess your code is the variable `response` (which is an array), then I would do:

```
response.sort(function(obj1, obj2){
  return obj2.bump - obj1.bump;
});
```

or if you want to also take in mind name order:

```
response.sort(function(obj1, obj2){
  var diff = obj2.bump - obj1.bump;
  var nameDiff = (obj2.name > obj1.name)?-1:((obj2.name < obj1.name)?1:0);
  return (diff == 0) ? nameDiff : diff;
});
```

Comment: Your first one will return C D A B, not C A D B. He wants the documents moved according to bumps – A and B both have 0 bumps, so they stay where they are. C has 2 bumps so it goes up 2, above A, so the list would be C A B D at this point. But then D has 1 bump so it goes up 1, above the B, so the final list is C A D B.

Comment: @Jed I guess he had written that wrongly. And my answer is interpreting bump as "order"...

Comment: Wouldn't this iterate the list? I'm admittedly not a MongoDB expert, but I'm not sure how you would sort a list in any language without iterating it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a purely query-based solution is possible with your document schema (I assume you have `createdDate` and `bump` fields). Instead, I suggest a single field called `sortorder` to keep track of your desired retrieval order:

1. `sortorder` is initially the creation timestamp. If there are no "bumps", sorting by this field gives the correct order.
2. If there is a "bump," the `sortorder` is invalidated. So simply correct the `sortorder` values: each time a "bump" occurs swap the `sortorder` fields of the bumped document and the document directly ahead of it. This literally "bumps" the document up in the sort order.
3. When querying, sort by `sortorder`.

You can remove fields `bump` and `createdDate` if they are not used elsewhere.

---

As an aside, most social sites don't directly manipulate a post's display position based on its number of votes (or "bumps"). Instead, the number of votes is used to calculate a score. Then the posts are sorted and displayed by this score. In your case, you should combine `createdDate` and `bumps` into a single score that *can* be sorted in a query.

This site (StackOverflow.com) had a related [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) about how to determine "hot" questions. I think there was even a competition to come up with a new formula. The meta question also shared the formulas used by two other popular social news sites: Y Combinator Hacker News and Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

Not a pleasant answer, but the solution you request is unrealistic. Here's my suggestion:

1. Add an `OrderPosition` property to your object instead of Bump.
2. Think of "bumping" as an event. It is best represented as an event-handler function. When an item gets "bumped" by whatever trigger in your business logic, the collection of items needs to be adjusted.

   ```
   var currentOrder = this.OrderPosition
   this.OrderPosition = currentOrder - bump;  // moves your object up the list
   // write a foreach loop here, iterating every item AFTER the items unadjusted
   // order, +1 to move them all down the list one notch.
   ```

This does require iterating through many items, and I know you are trying to prevent that, but I do not think there is any other way to safely ensure the integrity of your item ordering - especially when relative to other pulled collections that occur later down the road.

Comment: I think your approach is correct, but your implementation is off.  All you have to do is swap places with the item ahead of it. You shouldn't need to iterate the list, unless only to find the previous item.

Comment: @gilly3 You're correct if it were simply a list object and you were swapping places in it. But as I understand it, each item in the persistent collection has an order and if any are moved the others must be adjusted. Keeping this value on the object itself via a field means each record would need to be updated. Rather inefficient, but without knowing much about the problem I cant offer a better solution. :)